# multiple detail grids. One for each child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

So I have data like this:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "lock_version": 0,
        "parentField1": "LC",
        "parentField2": "G22 07/24 VS0",
        "parentField3": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
        "parentField4": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
        "parentField5": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
        "parent_children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "created_by": "John Doe",
                "created_on": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
                "modified_on": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
                "new_fields": [
                    "KA",
                    "KB",
                    "KC",
                    "KD",
                    "KE"
                ],
                "edited_fields": [
                    "KA",
                    "KB"
                ],
                "closed_fields": [
                    "KA",
                    "KB"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "created_by": "Jane Doe",
                "created_on": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
                "modified_on": "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
                "new_fields": [
                    "KA"
                ],
                "edited_fields": [
                    "KA",
                    "KB",
                    "KC",
                    "KD",
                    "KE"
                ],
                "closed_fields": [
                    "KA",
                    "KB"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "lock_version": 1,
        "parentField1": "LU",
        "parentField2": "G23 08/25 VS1",
        "parentField3": "2019-11-15T13:49:51.141Z",
        "parentField4": "2019-11-15T13:49:51.141Z",
        "parentField5": "2019-09-14T13:49:51.141Z",
        "parent_children": []
    }
]
```

What I have to do is to create layout with parent as master grid and nested detail grids for parent_children. But one grid for each child. What I was able to do is to create only one detail grid that shows grid containing all children.

I did it like this: html:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;"
  [masterDetail]="true"
  [isRowMaster]="isRowMaster"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [getRowId]="getRowId"
  [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
  [rowData]="(rowData$ | async) ?? []"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Ts:

```js
 public isRowMaster: IsRowMaster = (dataItem: any) => {
    return dataItem ? dataItem.parent_children.length > 0 : false;
  };

  public columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: '',
      children: [
        { field: 'parentField1' },
        { field: 'parentField2' },
        {
          field: 'parentField3',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Group2',
      children: [
        { field: 'parentField4' },
        { field: 'parentField5', columnGroupShow: 'open' },
        {
          field: 'parentField6',
          columnGroupShow: 'open',
          hide: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  public getRowId: GetRowIdFunc = (params: GetRowIdParams) => {
    return params.data.id;
  };

  public detailCellRendererParams: any = {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: 'created_by',
        },
        {
          field: 'created_on',
        },
        {
          field: 'modified_on',
        },
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: (params: any) => {
      params.successCallback(params.data.parent_children);
    },
  };
```

If I deal with this problem I would like to have created_by and created_on fields of child as a header of only column in child grid.

What I have tried was to try to define another detail grid options like this

```js
public anotherDetailCellRendererParams: any = {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        //here list of fields
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: (params: any) => {
      params.successCallback(params.data.new_fields);
    },
  };
```

and add this to detailCellRendererParams of ...detailCellRendererParams. But it doesn't work and doesn't look like good solution at all. So how can I create multiple detail grids, one for each element from `parent_children`?

Comment: Is this different to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732281/multiple-detail-grids-one-for-each-child-object ?